# Theme not Changing in `AppBar of material-UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the theme of a material-UI `AppBar` using states but the theme is not changing but the icons are.

Here the link of the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-bird-n30bg?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:)

In App.js, there is a typo -- **palatte** should be **palette**

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: { //<---here
      type: themeMode,
      primary: {
        main: themeMode === "light" ? "#3f51b5" : "#333333"
      }
    }
  });
```

I have checked & with the the typo fix, everything is working